# Can a preposition have the form of superlative?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, superlative-degree, whiz-deletion

> They had almost reached the door when a voice spoke from the chair
>   **nearest** them, "I can't believe you're going to do this.”

I guess ***nearest*** is at the place of preposition. Can a preposition have the form of superlative?

Comment: Relevant paper by Joan Maling (1883): http://people.brandeis.edu/~maling/Maling1983_adjectives.pdf It says "*near* is best analyzed as an adjective" (p. 270)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Near** is a bit of an unusual 'frozen' word. It was originally the *comparative* form of *nigh* (from OE *nior*). The terms **nearer** and **nearest** came later as speakers reinterpreted *near* as a positive form.

In addition **near** is rather vague with respect to its word class. The OED Online at *near, adv.2 (and prep.2)* notes the "difficulty of distinguishing the adjectival, adverbial, and prepositional or quasi-prepositional uses" of the word.

Regarding the comparative and superlative "prepositional" uses, the OED (ibid.) says:

> When the noun or noun phrase is the direct complement of near , this
>   acquires practically the force of a preposition, but **differs from true
>   prepositions in having comparative and superlative forms**.

...(emphasis mine) which is exactly the case here. In short, it looks like a preposition, but it's a sneaky adverb.

---

Also, at least in etymological origin, the **to** in "near/-er/-est *to* them" was actually a later addition to the idiom from Middle English, so it's not well-motivated to regard "near them" as a to-deletion as opposed to retention of an earlier form.

> Old Icelandic nær (like Old English nēar ) might be used either alone
>   or with a noun complement in the dative case. Both usages were adopted
>   in Middle English, and **a further construction introduced by the use
>   of to before the noun**.

Comment: +1 Suggested modification: "a cunning adjective masquerading as a sneaky adverb".

Answer (score 5):

It is a clever example, but most will consider this to be a shortened form of **nearest to them**. Adjectives can take prepositional phrase complements, and of course are the only word class which takes superlative marking.

This is a nice example of how linguistic data is frequently "corrected" by linguistic theory.

Comment: Comparative and [superlative adverbs](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_superlative_adverb) also exist, eg, "She ran fast, but he ran faster". "They sang more loudly than we did, but you sang most loudly" (not a great sentence, I admit, but grammatical nonetheless).

Comment: I respectfully disagree that any "shortened form" should be replaced by some theoretical but un-uttered "longer form" in cases like this. The utterance was "nearest them" and is well-attested.

Comment: @Mark: Where does jlovegren say that it "should be replaced"? And where is your evidence that "nearest to them" is "_unuttered_"? It is uttered, but not as often as "_nearest them_" (in writing at least).

Comment: @BillFranke My apologies for lack of clarity. Substitute "should be replaced by" with "should be analyzed as" and "un-uttered" with "un-uttered (by that speaker)". My point stands.

Comment: @MarkBeadles it's a legitimate methodological question to raise. if you like make a question of it on Linguistics SE.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good example of how useless [traditional parts of speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56656/15299) are.
And how much confusion results from searching for them.

As usual, many markers have been deleted from a clause, producing an opaque (but much shorter) result. Below, the deleted markers are in boldface:

- *a voice spoke from the chair **which was the** nearest **chair** to them*

As you can see, *nearest* is not a preposition, but a simple predicate adjective which happens to be inflected with the superlative *-est*. The repeated NP *the chair* is deleted in context, leaving only *nearest to them*, which could be perfectly ordinary in a relative clause

- *a voice spoke from the chair **which was** nearest to them*

And then [*Whiz*-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299) gets rid of *which was*, thus destroying the evidence of the relative clause, and producing what looks like it might be a very strange prepositional phrase indeed. But isn't.

Comment: I’ve always puzzled that *near the door, nearer the door, nearest the door* looks rather like we’re inflecting a preposition as though it were an adjective or adverb.

Comment: But of course, it's not a preposition; it's an adjective and therefore may be fearlessly inflected.

Comment: The mentioned part of question (ie, “a voice spoke from the chair nearest them”) has no *to* in it; perhaps boldface *to* in your bullets? And explain loss of *to*?

Comment: _Near_, and therefore _nearest_, doesn't require _to_. _She lives near (to) me_.

Answer (score 3):

Prepositions are thrown into the *adverb* category. Some adverbs have comparative and superlative forms, yes, and some, eg *to, by, for. from*, don't. "...from the chair **nearest (to)**  them" is grammatical English.

But "near" in the phrase *a voice spoke **from** the chair nearest them* functions as a locative adverb as well as a preposition. "**From**" is the first preposition in that prepositional phrase, and "**nearest (to)**" is the second (but the *to* has been elided, and whether or not it's there is a matter of style and idiom).

[Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nearest%20to%20you,%20nearest%20you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that both phrases are used, but that *nearest you* is at least 4 times more frequent than *nearest to you*.

Comment: Yes, viewing *near* as an adverb is the best way to analyze it.